# Как сложить условия в DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

Создал игрушечный DateFrame. Хочу решить проблему с условиями, а трактуется вот так:

- вывести всех, кто старше 40
- вывести всех, кто имеет доход выше среднего по датасету
- вывести всех, кто имеет доход выше среднего по датасету, но надежность ниже среднего по датасету

Ну так я это сделал.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
'имя': ['Петя', 'Вася', 'Аня', 'Света'],
'возраст': [45, 26, 41 , 21],
'доход': [100000, 80000, 150000, 60000],
'надежность клиента (0..1)': [0.65, 0.74, 0.87, 0.68],
'пол': ['муж', 'муж', 'жен', 'жен']},
index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

print(df[df['возраст'] > 40])
print(df[df['доход'] > df.iloc[:, 2].mean() ])                  #вот тут и есть проблема
print(df[df['надежность клиента (0..1)'] < df.iloc[:, 3].mean()])   


df.head()
```

Как сделать так чтобы все эти 3 условия выходили в одну табличку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, запомнить битовые маски в переменных и потом комбинировать их через логическое и, чтобы не повторять условия:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'имя': ['Петя', 'Вася', 'Аня', 'Света'],
'возраст': [45, 26, 41 , 21],
'доход': [100000, 80000, 150000, 60000],
'надежность клиента (0..1)': [0.65, 0.74, 0.87, 0.68],
'пол': ['муж', 'муж', 'жен', 'жен']},
index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

age_above_40 = df['возраст'] > 40
print(df[age_above_40])

income_above_mean = df['доход'] > df['доход'].mean()
print(df[income_above_mean])

reliability_below_mean = df['надежность клиента (0..1)'] < df['надежность клиента (0..1)'].mean()
print(df[income_above_mean & reliability_below_mean])     

choosen = pd.DataFrame({
    'показатель': ['старше 40', 'имеет доход выше среднего', 'имеет доход выше среднего, но надежность ниже среднего'],
    'имена': [df.loc[age_above_40, 'имя'].to_list(),
              df.loc[income_above_mean, 'имя'].to_list(), 
              df.loc[income_above_mean & reliability_below_mean, 'имя'].to_list()]
})
```

Содержимое `choosen`:

```
                                          показатель    имена
0   старше 40                                           [Петя, Аня]
1   имеет доход выше среднего                           [Петя, Аня]
2   имеет доход выше среднего, но надежность ниже ...   [Петя]
```

Comment: Ну, выводится же 3 таблицы. А можно как то все в одно объединить?

Comment: @Олег Приведите пример - как вы видите такую таблицу, учитывая, что у неё будет разное кол-вое строк для каждой из выборок и разные имена в выборке?

Comment: @Олег Добавил такой вариант в ответ

Comment: воот, так и думал, что можно было сделать. Спасибо :)